# jQuery Find() Initiated from Self or Parent Objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm aware of the latest `.addBack()` functionality but having looked at it I'm not sure whether it can provide a solution to my task. I've cobbled together a solution, but as with everything jQuery there may be a more appropriate off-the-shelf way of achieving what I need to do.

Here's what I've come up with so far/by way of an explanation and what I'm trying to achieve:

```
function getInputs($obj) {
    return ($obj.hasClass("input-wrapper")
        ? $obj
        : $obj.find(".input-wrapper")).find(":input");
}
```

1. The function must return all inputs that are children of an
   `.input-wrapper`.
2. `$obj` can be an `.input-wrapper` itself or an object further up the
   tree.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: If you cannot guarantee that `$obj` will be the `.input-wrapper` element, then the code you have is about as succinct as you're going to get.

Comment: An input collection should always be a descendant of an input-wrapper (it's direct parent), but it can also be part of a group, a control or a group of controls. The common denominator is that I only want inputs that are descendants of input-wrapper, hence I abstracted this functionality out to ensure that is always the case. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: It may be more beneficial to post a sample of the HTML which contains all the scenarios covering when you want to find `.input-wrapper`

Comment: I'm happy with your previous answer Rory. I'm no jQuery specialist so I just wanted to ensure I wasn't reinventing the wheel if there was something out there.